# How to change File URL in file uploaded to s3 compatible storage with self written plugin

Tags: plugins, uploads, attachments, meta-value

I'm trying to write a plugin that uploads files directly to an S3 storage and allows to downloads them like files directly on the server. The main page of the plugin contains the following code for this

```
function main_upload() {
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/upload.php">
        <input type="file" name="myfile"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
```

upload.php contains

```
<?php
    require "/var/www/html/wp-load.php";
    
    function s3_upload(){
        //do all the s3 stuff
    };

    $response = s3_upload();
```

Where response is:

```
Aws\Result Object ( 
[data:Aws\Result:private] => Array ( 
    [Expiration] => [ETag] => "b6174e541d6069c13a9d8352d5fc4336" 
    [ServerSideEncryption] => [VersionId] => [SSECustomerAlgorithm] => [SSECustomerKeyMD5] => [SSEKMSKeyId] => [SSEKMSEncryptionContext] => [RequestCharged] => [@metadata] => Array ( 
        [statusCode] => 200 
        [effectiveUri] => https://bucket.s3.mydomain.de/55f012ad21... 
        [headers] => Array ( 
            [date] => Thu, 04 Mar 2021 13:44:00 GMT 
            [connection] => KEEP-ALIVE 
            [server] => myStorage/1.0.0.0 
            [x-amz-request-id] => 1614865440609335 
            [x-amz-id-2] => 12131130 [content-length] => 0 
            [etag] => "b6174e541d6069c13a9d8352d5fc4336" ) 
            [transferStats] => Array ( 
                [http] => Array ( 
                    [0] => Array ( ) ) ) ) 
    [ObjectURL] => https://bucket.s3.mydomain.de/55f012ad21... ) 
    [monitoringEvents:Aws\Result:private] => Array ( ) )
```

Now I want to add this file to media library and set "File URL" in wordpress to "ObjectURL" from response. Therefore, the upload.php also contains:

```
$file = $_FILES["myfile"];
$filename = $file["name"];
$fileType = $file["type"];
$fileURL = $response["ObjectURL"]; 
$fileSize = $file["size"];
$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $fileURL,
    'post_mime_type' => $fileType,
    'post_title' => $filename,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);

$parent_post_id = 0;

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $filename, $parent_user_id);
```

From this point on, the medium is in S3 storage and in the database. However, the File URL is

> http://server.ip/wp_content/uploads/filename

Of course there is no file at this place and the download is empty. How can I change the File URL now?

**Additional information:**
It seems that the GUID is used as the File URL if the filename is set to "", i.e. left blank. So in upload.php

```
$filename = "";
```

Is this a bug that will be fixed or can I rely on this behavior to be maintained?